# how to convert props content which has html tags html and display it instead of displaying it as string?

Tags: reactjs

Need to display the html content from props.

```
var templateData="<div><div>some text</div><div>some more text</div></div>"
 <Modal content={templateData} />
```

In the calling component `{content}` is only displaying the html tags but isn't rendering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you pass it like `var templateData="..."` it will always be an string.

What you need to do is pass it like `var templateData=<div><div>some text</div><div>some more text</div></div>` and then render it with `< />`

e.g.

```
<Modal content={templateData} />
```

And inside `Modal`

```
let Content = this.props.content // or in props.content in functional components
return (
    <Content />
)
```

If you are getting the string from a external call and you can't add the html in the code, you can use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` like Anil Kumar said, but this is very dangerous and not recommended

Answer (score 0):

You can use below snippet:

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: templateData }} />
```